# rabbitmq and vhosts and what needs to get setup in AD and how rabbitmq works with the names

Tags: ldap, rabbitmq

Little confused on rabbitmq and vhosts here.  The standard generic example 
they have in their docs:

```
   `[
  {rabbit, [{auth_backends, [rabbit_auth_backend_ldap]}]},
  {rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap,
   [ {servers,               ["my-ldap-server"]},
     {user_dn_pattern,       "cn=${username},ou=People,dc=example,dc=com"},
     {use_ssl,               false},
     {port,                  389},
     {log,                   false},
     {vhost_access_query,    {in_group,
                              "ou=${vhost}-users,ou=vhosts,dc=example,dc=com"}},
     {resource_access_query,
      {for, [{permission, configure, {in_group, "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com"}},
             {permission, write,
              {for, [{resource, queue,    {in_group, 
"cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com"}},
                     {resource, exchange, {constant, true}}]}},
             {permission, read,
              {for, [{resource, exchange, {in_group, 
"cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com"}},
                     {resource, queue,    {constant, true}}]}}
            ]
      }},
     {tag_queries,           [{administrator, {constant, false}},
                              {management,    {constant, true}}]}
   ]
  }
].`
```

Question is for the line:
    `{vhost_access_query,    {in_group,
                              "ou=${vhost}- users,ou=vhosts,dc=example,dc=com"}},`

Is the person expected to get the active directory administrators to create 
for a vhost for example called ABC in ldap the ou=ABC-
users,out=vhosts,dc=example,dc=com?

(if the actual domain for discussion purposes is actually example.com) :)

...and then the rabbitmq admin creates the vhost for example using the 
management plugin called ABC or /ABC?  (not sure about the slash).

I take it the ou=ABC-users,ou=vhosts,dc=example,dc=com can have 
cn=Department group1, cn=Department group2, etc and all under this will have 
access for example?

Is there something about the rabbitmq code that knows to use ${vhost}-users 
and ${vhost-groups} to associate with a vhost created in rabbitmq?  Is it 
looking for -users and -group tacked on to the ldap name and extracting the 
part in fron of -users and -group to then associate with a vhost?  Can I get 
away with using an existing group (e.g., 
cn=MYADGroup,ou=groups,dc=domain,dc=com and create a vhost called MYADGroup 
and it knows to associate that vhost_access_query to that vhost name?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution or get an answer on this?